# How can I change a Bootstrap list group on change of another?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, listitem

I have 2 list groups. The second is based off json data and filtered(2 if statements in the code)

This fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/andernathan/fL3cwoa2/32/ is a very simplified version of what I'm trying to do.

when you click on "Howdy" the second list shows "Howdy there" and "Howdy they're". When you click on "Howdee", I would like the second list to show just "Howdy their" (my second "if" statement)

Thanks...as always!

```js
const activities1 = [];
const activities2 = [];

var json = {
  "Tasks": [{
    "Subject": "Howdy their"
  }, {
    "Subject": "Howdy there"
  }, {
    "Subject": "Howdy they're"
  }]
}

var obj = json.Tasks;

for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
  activitySub = (obj[i].Subject);

  if (activitySub != "Howdy their") {
    activities1.push({
      activitySub,
    })
  }
  if (activitySub === "Howdy their") {
    activities2.push({
      activitySub,
    })
  }
}
console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(activities1)));
console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(activities2)));

const html = activities1.map(obj => {
  let item = document.querySelector('#template').innerHTML;
  item = item.replace('{sub}', obj.activitySub);
  return item;
});

document.querySelector('#list').innerHTML = html.join('');
```

```html
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="active">
    <a href="#"> Howdy</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"> Howdee</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<ul class="list-group">
  <div id="list"></div>
  <template id="template">
       <h5 class="media-heading">{sub}</h5>
      </template>
</ul>
```

Comment: That looks much better, but you haven't really explained the intended behavior. What should appear in the second list? Also, your second list is completely invalid. Divs and templates are not valid list children. I suggest a review of the [list group docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/list-group/#basic-example) and the [HTML list docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul).

Comment: Thank you. I'll have to review the list group docs. I don't know how to create a dynamic list from an array without "template" because that json array may have 20 items, it may have 2 but I'll look into it. 
That being said; when you click on "Howdy" your second list shows "Howdy there" and "Howdy they're".
When you click on "Howdee", I would like the second list to show just "Howdy their" (my second "if" statement).

Comment: Maybe the template element is ok. I admit that I'm not familiar with its use. The div definitely isn't. Please put that information in your question. It doesn't belong down here.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, perhaps I got carried away and made this too complicated, but perhaps this more generic approach helps.

You could start with this markup

```
<ul class="list-group" id="listOne">
  <li class="active">
    <a href="#">
      Howdy
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      Howdee
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul class="list-group" id="listTwo"></ul>
```

And do this in javascript

```
var visibleIndex = 0;

// added a second prop to the object to determine when it should be visible
var json = {"Tasks":[{"subject":"Howdy their", "showOn" : 0},{"subject":"Howdy there", "showOn" : 1},{"subject":"Howdy they're", "showOn" : 1}]}
var taskList = json.Tasks;

// store elements in vars to save queries for subsequent clicks
var listOne = document.getElementById('listOne');
var listTwo = document.getElementById('listTwo');
var listLinks = listOne.querySelectorAll('a');

// click lsitener for list One
// Just do something when index is changed
listLinks.forEach( (link, index) => {
    link.addEventListener('click', () => {
        var clickedIndex = index;
    if (clickedIndex !== visibleIndex) {
        visibleIndex = parseInt(clickedIndex);
        rebuildList();
    }
  })
});

function rebuildList() {
    // set clicked element to active
    listLinks.forEach( (link, index) => {
    if (index === visibleIndex) {
        link.parentElement.classList.add('active');
    } else {
        link.parentElement.classList.remove('active');
    }
  });
  
  // remove all elements from list two
  while( listTwo.firstChild ){
    listTwo.removeChild( listTwo.firstChild );
    }
  
  // add all elements where showOn is equal to visibelIndex
  taskList.forEach( taskObject => {
    if (taskObject.showOn === visibleIndex) {
        addToSecondList(taskObject.subject)
    }
  });
}

// Yeah, we use vanilla javascript to create elements
function addToSecondList(text) {
    var newItem = document.createElement('li');
  newItem.textContent = text;
  listTwo.appendChild(newItem);
}

// initially  build list with visibleIndex 0, perhaps not needed
rebuildList(visibleIndex);
```